# Custom UINavigationBar animation

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uinavigationbar

I've subclassed UINavigationBar in order to set a custom background image.

I'm using it to initialize a UINavigationController with:

```
-(id)initWithNavigationBarClass:(Class)navigationBarClass toolbarClass:(Class)toolbarClass
```

The problem is that when new UIViewControllers get pushed on to the NavigationController stack, the title text animates in from the right across the background image in a way that looks a bit sucky.

Problem: How to tweak the animation so e.g. it fades in as it animates across.

The closest I've come is by creating a custom fade-up animation in the pushed/popped ViewController class. I use a NSTimer to trigger changes to the alpha of the titleView:

```
UILabel *titleView = (UILabel *)self.navigationItem.titleView;

...

-(void)setAlpha:(float)alpha
{
   titleView.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:grayShade green:grayShade blue:grayShade alpha:alpha];
}
```

However, if I trigger this in 'ViewDidAppear' it's already too late and the fade-up starts after the new view has finished sliding in. I figured that I could trigger it in 'ViewWillAppear' but that this might lead to indeterminate and inconsistent timings on different devices. Am I right in this assumption and if so, how can I customize the animation in the way I want to?